# Android menu order/shopping cart using intent to another activity only show what is selected OR Textview automatically add as much as item selected

Tags: android

I want to make self order restaurant. On first activity it shows all menu (total 10 menu), each menu has button "+" and "-" as counter how much menu order. In the bottom of this activity, there is a Button called "Submit". When button submit clicked, I send data via Intent to second activity.. (Like SHOPPING CART)

How can I just show what item selected only, without making 10 textview...??

Comment: this is not duplicate question... I can't find the answer.. hlp me,,

Comment: As I understand it, you want to pass text between Activities. Therefore, the duplicate.

Comment: I already know how to pass text between activities.. I want to ask how to textview automatically added as much as item selected,, without declare 10 textviews,,

Comment: Then, just pass an array of strings (or a joined string you will split in the other Activity) to the second Activity, and build a ListView accordingly.